# Why can't I see in a temporary table after inserting data?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Here is how I created a temporary table

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMP_TABLE  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM VIEW_1
)
```

The following SQL returns nothing...

```
SELECT * FROM TMP_TABLE
```

I tried to insert a record again by issuing the following query

```
INSERT INTO TMP_TABLE (COL_1, COL_2, COL_3, COL_4, COL_5, COL_6) 
VALUES ('00000000', '2445883',  '20140401', '20990331', '20160401', '20170331')
```

Nothing appears in the table...

What might I have done wrong?

Comment: Are you running your queries in the same user session as the inserts?

Comment: DId you perform `COMMIT`???

Comment: As APC pointed out, temp table records are persisted per-session.  You cannot "see" them from another session. Or you did not do a commit as Pons suggested.

Comment: Yes, I did run the query in the same session and commit right after that

Comment: 1. open up a database client
2. open a new session(sql editor)
3. run all the query 
This is what I did.

Comment: Are you sure it's really the same DB session - you might be using a SQL worksheet in one session and looking at the table data in another session, even if they're just different dinwos in your client (e.g. SQL Developer)? If you insert and query in the same worksheet/editor do you see the same thing? Which client are you using?

Comment: yes, i did run all the queries on the same editor. I will cehck if this is database client specific thing or not.